# handle direct url with history api in asp.mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I have my site like  http://mysite.com/ and on the index page i have search box and for the result i am using jqgrid. When user click row in the jqgrid row I am taking data from cells and do ajax call to server and fetch json data and once data arrived I hide the search box and jqgrid and show another div which is I kept for result. In short, user will be on the same page just div's hide/show.

Now I have seen history api and used pushState and popstate so my url becomes in the addressbar like http://mysite.com/controller/action/para1/para2 (here para1 and para2 are the parameters i am passing to action). Everything is ok so far.

Now the problem is if I copy this URL "http://mysite.com/controller/action/para1/para2" and if I open this with let's say different browser and hit enter it display just json data. So, I am confused that how to handle when user directly use that url in controller.

I was thinking to check in the controller action if the request is AJAX then return json data otherwise full page, is that right approach? OR something on the client side we have so that it load the same way as earlier.

Thanks

Comment: nobody have any answer

Comment: I'd like to confirm what you are trying to do. I think you intend to alter history url's in 1 browser (like chrome), then try to use the same altered url in another browser (like firefox). is that correct?

Comment: no. What I want to achieve is i have search page and on the same page I have display results in side one div within jquery grid. Now when user click any of the row in jquery grid I use history api and change the address bar with new url and on the result page only i hide/show another div for details but now if user copy that url and paste into another instance of the same or different browser (I don't care) and press enter it only display json data because its ajax call only so how to deal with that so that it also display the same page even user directly access the url

Comment: I think I understand better. Please add your Ajax Action Method to your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if I copy this URL "http://mysite.com/controller/action/para1/para2" and if I open this with let's say different browser and hit enter it display just json data.
>
> > it only display json data because its ajax call only so how to deal with that so that it also display the same page even user directly access the url.

I think what you're looking for is `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`:

```
public class FooController : Controller {
    public ActionResult GetFoo(int id) {
        var model = _fooService.Get(id);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("_Foo", model);

        return View("Foo", model);
    }
}
```

Note: It's recommended to use WebAPI controllers to handle only json data. So if the user got there by typing the url the mvc controller will handle it and if you need to get the json data for that view you could call the webapi controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate controller or action method for AJAX and for Views. The View controller should match the URL. The Ajax controller should be the less "pretty" URL since it's behind the scenes.

You need to set up a routing definition in global.asax (MVC 3) or App_Start/RouteConfig.cs (MVC 4) to handle the parameters if you haven't already done that.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRoute",
            "MyUrlController/{action}/{para1}/{para2}",
            new
                {
                    action = "Index",
                    para1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    para2 = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
                );
```

Then in the **View** controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string para1 = "Default Value", string para2 = "Default Value")
    {
        // ...Handle parameters...

        return View("_MyView", viewModel);
    }
```

Returning a View object type is the key. The History API URL doesn't get it's data from the same AJAX source controller which returns a PartialViewResult.

Comment: This will not work on asp.net mvc3, please read this: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx.

Comment: Controller and perhaps action just need to be statically named. But this is why I also stated that the AJAX call should be on a separate controller.

Comment: I was just pointing out that in mvc3 it's not easy to route two consecutive optional parameters.

Comment: OK, I see the issue there. So a better way might be to give para1 a default value and make para2 the only optional value.